# I'm getting "Segmentation Fault(Core dump)" when i'm running a socket related program

Tags: c, sockets

I had googled when segmentation error is caused but i'm not able to correct the error in my code.I'm using the select function to find out which file descriptors are readable.I'm fairly new in socket programming in c and i can't understand the purpose of the structure socklen_t when we have macros for ipv4 address length.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>

#define PORT "9034"

int main()
{
    fd_set master,read_fds;
    int file_descriptor,new_fd,server,yes=1,error,fd_max,i;
    char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN],data[1024];
    struct addrinfo hints,*p;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t addrlen; //?
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    FD_ZERO(&master);
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    hints.ai_family=AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol=AI_PASSIVE;
    file_descriptor=getaddrinfo(NULL,PORT,&hints,&p);
    printf("%s",inet_ntop(AF_INET,p->ai_addr,ip,addrlen));
    server=socket(p->ai_family,p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol);
    setsockopt(server,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int));
    listen(server,5);
    FD_SET(server,&master);
    fd_max=server;
    while (1)
    {
        read_fds=master;
        select(fd_max+1,&read_fds,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        for(i=0;i<fd_max;i++)
        {
            if(i==server)
            {
                new_fd=accept(server,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,&addrlen);
                FD_SET(new_fd,&master);
                printf("Connected to the client %s on socket %d",inet_ntop(AF_INET,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,ip,INET_ADDRSTRLEN),new_fd);
                if(new_fd>fd_max)
                fd_max=new_fd;
            }
            else
            {
                recv(i,data,sizeof(data),0);
                printf("%s",data);                
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in the code does the seg fault occur?  Do you have warnings turned on in your compiler?  Are you running in debug mode so you can step through to see just what happens at each statement?

Comment: Consider the fact that the structures for IPv4 and IPv6 are different sizes and yet passed via the same pointer. The only way for the callee to know what it got is via that size variable. Also many of these methods can fail, you need to check the error conditions described in the documentation.

Comment: @ryyker for some reason the objects master and read_fds are being shown as <error-type> and FD_SET,FD_INIT functions are to return a integer and when i'm trying to assign to an integer, i'm getting this error "assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'void'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is here:

```
file_descriptor=getaddrinfo(NULL,PORT,&hints,&p);
printf("%s",inet_ntop(AF_INET,p->ai_addr,ip,addrlen));
```

Note that in the second line, you are dereferencing the pointer `p` -- but `p` is NULL because `getaddrinfo()` failed and didn't set it to a valid address, so trying to dereference invokes undefined behavior, and in this instance, causes a crash.

Btw I was able to debug this by inserting temporary `printf()` statements at various points in the program and seeing what did (or did not) get printed.  In particular:

```
 printf("k1\n");
     file_descriptor=getaddrinfo(NULL,PORT,&hints,&p);
 printf("k2 file_descriptor=%i p=%p\n", file_descriptor, p);
     printf("%s",inet_ntop(AF_INET,p->ai_addr,ip,addrlen));
 printf("k3\n");
```

... when I ran with the code like that, I saw this output:

```
 k1
 k2 file_descriptor=12 p=0x0
 Segmentation fault: 11
```

... which makes the problem apparent -- p was NULL (aka 0x0) at the "k2" line, and the crash occurred before the "k3" line got printed, so that crash was definitely in your `printf()` call, and due to the NULL-pointer dereference.

To fix the crash, you'll need to check the return value of `getaddrinfo()` to make sure it returned zero/success, and handle it gracefully when it returns non-zero/error, instead of just assuming it will always succeed.  (in general you need to do that with all function calls that return a success/failure value)

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, it appears that some of the utilities you are using may not be defined correctly.  For what ever libraries you are pulling into your project, make sure you are using the correct (and corresponding) header files.  i.e. for POSIX development this one is suggested:

```
/* According to POSIX.1-2001 */
#include <sys/select.h>
```

( *[More here about that](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set)* )

I do not see the `select.h` file mentioned in your `#include` statements.

Comment: This solved the <error-type>, but still getting the error "Segmentation fault(Core dumped)" on running the code